# Is there any need to switch to modules when migrating to Java 9 or later?

Tags: java, java-11, java-9, java-platform-module-system

We're currently migrating from Java 8 to Java 11. However, upgrading our services was less painful, than we anticipated. We basically only had to change the version number in our `build.gradle` file and the services were happily up and running. We upgraded libraries as well as (micro) services that use those libs. No problems until now.

Is there any *need* to actually switch to modules? This would generate needless costs IMHO. Any suggestion or further reading material is appreciated.

To clarify, are there any consequences if Java 9+ code is used without introducing modules? E.g. can it become incompatible with other code?

Comment: It's the same risk you already faced in Java 8: ending up in "Classpath Hell".

Comment: The [sotms/#summary](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#summary) would answer to an extent. You can check, if your project goals are aligned to the project [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/). Apart from that, in my opinion, its a matter of being up to date as well that matters for libraries/services providing support to its consumers.

Comment: @Taschi I don't think classpath hell alone justifies going modular, as all code prior to Java 9 had that issue and in most case we've been fine with it (personally never had a problem with it).

Comment: @Naman bringing up the goals of project jigsaw is indeed a very good argument.

Comment: @Younes El Ouarti, removing "Classpath Hell" is one of the two stated goals of Project Jigsaw. If you think that it is not a sufficient reason for dealing with Jigsaw, well... I agree with you, and I avoid Jigsaw whenever I can.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

No.

There is no need to switch to modules.

There has never been a need to switch to modules.

Java 9 and later releases support traditional JAR files on the
traditional class path, via the concept of the unnamed module, and will
likely do so until the heat death of the universe.

Whether to start using modules is entirely up to you.

If you maintain a large legacy project that isn’t changing very much,
then it’s probably not worth the effort.

If you work on a large project that’s grown difficult to maintain over
the years then the clarity and discipline that modularization brings
could be beneficial, but it could also be a lot of work, so think
carefully before you begin.

If you’re starting a new project then I highly recommend starting with
modules if you can.  Many popular libraries have, by now, been [upgraded
to be modules](https://github.com/sormuras/modules), so there’s a good
chance that all of the dependencies that you need are already available
in modular form.

If you maintain a library then I strongly recommend that you
upgrade it to be a module if you haven’t done so already, and if all of
your library’s dependencies have been converted.

All this isn’t to say that you won’t encounter a few stumbling blocks
when moving past Java 8.  Those that you do encounter will, however,
likely have nothing to do with modules *per se*.  The most common
migration problems that we’ve heard about since we released Java 9 in
2017 have to do with [changes to the syntax of the version
string](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/322) and to the [removal or
encapsulation of internal APIs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260)
(*e.g.*, `sun.misc.Base64Decoder`) for which public, supported
replacements have been available for years.

Answer (score 39):

I can only tell you my organization opinion on the matter. We *are* in the process of moving to modules, for every single project that we are working on. What we are building is basically micro-services + some client libraries. For micro-services the transition to `modules` is somehow a lower priority: the code there is already somehow isolated in the docker container, so "adding" modules in there does not seem (to us) very important. This work is being picked up slowly, but it's low priority.

On the other hand, client libraries is an entirely different story. I can not tell you the mess we have sometimes. I'll explain one point that I hated before `jigsaw`. You expose an interface to clients, for everyone to use. Automatically that `interface` is `public` - exposed to the world. Usually, what I do, is have then some `package-private` classes, that are not exposed to the clients, that use that interface. I don't want clients to use that, it is internal. Sounds good? Wrong.

The first problem is that when those `package-private` classes grow, and you want more classes, the only way to keep everything hidden is to create classes in *the same* package:

```
  package abc:
        -- /* non-public */ Usage.java
        -- /* non-public */ HelperUsage.java
        -- /* non-public */ FactoryUsage.java
        ....
```

When it grows (in our cases it does), those packages are way too big. Moving to a separate package you say? Sure, but then that `HelperUsage` and `FactoryUsage` will be `public` and we tried to avoid that from the beginning.

Problem number two: any user/caller of our clients can create *the same package* name and extend those hidden classes. It happened a few times to us already, fun times.

`modules` solves this problem in a beautiful way : `public` is not *really* `public` anymore; I can have `friend` access via `exports to` directive. This makes our code lifecycle and management much easier. And we get away from classpath hell. Of course `maven/gradle` handle that for us, mainly, but when *there is* a problem, the pain will be very real. There could be many other examples, too.

That said, transition is (still) not easy. First of all, everyone on the team needs to be aligned; second there are hurdles. The biggest two I still see is: how do you separate each module, based on what, specifically? I don't have a definite answer, yet. The second is `split-packages`, oh the beautiful "same class is exported by different modules". If this happens with your libraries, there are ways to mitigate; but if these are external libraries... not *that* easy.

If you depend on `jarA` and `jarB` (separate modules), but they both export `abc.def.Util`, you are in for a surprise. There are ways to solve this, though. Somehow painful, but solvable.

Overall, since we migrated to modules (and still do), our code has become *much* cleaner. And if your company is "code-first" company, this matters. On the other hand, I have been involved in companies were this was seen as "too expensive", "no real benefit" by senior architects.

Comment: Thanks for the incites! So what I'm getting is, that the modularization comes with the much need access restrictions we've been missing in previous versions. I can definitely see how this is useful for libraries. In case a service is communicated with via REST/AMQP/etc. this is again not so much of an issue, or rather, there are no benefits? Maybe we can't arbitrarily say that *all* java 9+ code should be modular? So we should regard it as a "tool" itself? Interesting nevertheless.

Comment: What you could find useful is an "accessor" API pattern (but please note that instead of a public static field, a private one with methods is preferred, to avoid deadlocks during class loading). See here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/API_Design#Allow_access_only_from_a_friend_code

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience! It would be good if you would share more details or links to the problems you mentioned that re painful, but still solvable.

Comment: “Problem number two: any user/caller of our clients can create *the same package* name and extend those hidden classes.”  Long before Java 9, packages could be [sealed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) to prevent this.  (I happen to think modules are an excellent idea and I use them in all my projects.  I just wanted to point out that this particular use case doesn’t require them.)