# Package 'org.pmml4s.model' is declared in module with an invalid name ('pmml4s.2.10')

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, scikit-learn, pmml

I'm trying to use [PMML4S](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s) to make predictions from an imported model from sklearn. I have the model in an xml file that I am trying to load into java using pmml4s. I am trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-scikit-learn-model-into-java-app-96d776b84c44). However, I am having issues getting it to work: specifically, "**Package 'org.pmml4s.model' is declared in module with an invalid name ('pmml4s.2.10')**" . I am using IntelliJ as my IDE. Please let me know if I can provide other information/code. Any help is appreciated!

Error is here:

```
import org.pmml4s.model.Model;
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pmml4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml4s_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>doctor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used java 9 modules in your project and imported a library which was not converted to java 9 modules. Thus Java treats this library as an automatic module and derives module name from jar name. The jar name happens to be illegal.

See:

- [What is an automatic module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)

You have 2 options:

**Option 1: Dont use java9 modules**

See:

- [Is there any need to switch to modules when migrating to Java 9 or later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950667/is-there-any-need-to-switch-to-modules-when-migrating-to-java-9-or-later)

**Option 2: Sanitize jar name**

See:

- [Unable to derive module descriptor for auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)
- [Scala Suffix Maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397446/1570854) looks like a tool designed precisely to solve your problem

Note that you need to require the automatic module in this approach:

- [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module)

Comment: I added the plugin to the pom.xml file as option 2 suggests. The error now reads, **"java: package org.pmml4s.model is not visible
  (package org.pmml4s.model is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.example.doctor does not read it)"**

Comment: Have you modified your app module to read it? See updated answer